# Bootstrap Multiselect Dropdown renders empty dropdown

Tags: javascript, .net, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to utilize [bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) for a dropdown element on my view with the following code:

```
<select id="msDropdown" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#msDropdown').multiselect();
});
```

When the view is rendered, two dropdown elements are included: The bootstrap dropdown and an empty dropdown:
[image: (1)bootstrap dropdown, (2)empty dropdown, (3)selected]
From the third panel above you can also see that the two dropdowns are associated.  When selections are made in the first dropdown, the titles of both dropdowns are updated.

Finally, if the .multiselect() javascript command is not included, only the empty dropdown is displayed.  Whats the deal with the empty dropdown - why does it appear at all and how do I get rid of it?

Thanks in advance!

edit: [A jsfiddle with intended behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/cqs8orft/).  And yet in my application, two dropdowns are displayed :\

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem. Not really clear what your issue is

Comment: I could do that, but I have no doubt it will work in a quarantined demo environment.  Whatever the issue is here must be due to some other interaction w/ my application.  I was hoping someone would have experienced this same problem before and be able to recommend a solution. :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have another bootstrap plugin for `<select>` elements whose initializer was a tad overzealous - it would search the DOM for all matching elements and bootstrappify them, resulting in a duplicate dropdown in this instance.  Updating this other plugin's selector from:

```
$('select').selectpicker();
```

to

```
$('select:not(#msDropdown)').selectpicker();
```

solved the problem.